# How to Select column from joined table in PL/SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm creating a PL/SQL function that returns an employe's information, by asking for the employee's id. The function get this code/ID and searches for the employee's info.

My problem is that I also need to add another column that I get from joining another table but I get `PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "EMPLOYE"."IDEMPLOYE" : identificateur non valide`. is it possible to?

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fNombreProjet(id_employe IN employe.idemploye%type) 
    RETURN sys_refcursor is data_emp sys_refcursor; 
BEGIN
    OPEN data_emp for
    SELECT  emp_recherché.IDEMPLOYE ,emp_recherché.NOMEMPLOYE
    FROM Employe emp_recherché
    WHERE idEmploye = id_employe;
    RETURN data_emp;
END;    
/

SELECT fNombreProjet(2000) result FROM dual;
```

this is the query Im trying to join in the PL/SQL select (where the column I want is count(*))

```
SELECT  employe.IDEMPLOYE, employe.NOMEMPLOYE, count(*) 
FROM employe
join ressourcesprojet on employe.idemploye=ressourcesprojet.idemploye
group by  employe.IDEMPLOYE, employe.NOMEMPLOYE;
```

The PL/SQL mix of the two Ive been trying without success.(Doesnt work)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fNombreProjet(id_employe IN employe.idemploye%type) 
    RETURN sys_refcursor is data_emp sys_refcursor; 
BEGIN
    OPEN data_emp for
    SELECT  emp_recherché.IDEMPLOYE ,emp_recherché.NOMEMPLOYE, count(*)
    FROM Employe emp_recherché 
    join ressourcesprojet on employe.idemploye=ressourcesprojet.idemploye
    WHERE idEmploye = id_employe
    group by emp_recherché.IDEMPLOYE ,emp_recherché.NOMEMPLOYE;
    RETURN data_emp;
END;    
/
```

Comment: *it doesnt allow me to* - always post full, exact error messages when asking for help

Comment: Try to provide an alias for `count(*)`

Comment: Non-aggregated columns list next to **select** don't match with the column list next to **group by** for the second stored function. So, not expected to compile with success. Btw, try to use shorter aliases, the current alias is even longer than the table name.

Comment: @CaiusJard PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHERE" when expecting one of the following

Comment: WHERE goes before GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I had to use `emp_rechercé` instead of `employe` and place where before the group by. And a few more little details. here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fNombreProjet(id_employe IN employe.idemploye%type) 
    RETURN sys_refcursor is data_emp sys_refcursor; 
BEGIN
    OPEN data_emp for
    SELECT  emp_recherché.IDEMPLOYE ,emp_recherché.NOMEMPLOYE, count(*)
    FROM Employe emp_recherché 
    join ressourcesprojet on emp_recherché.idemploye=ressourcesprojet.idemploye
    WHERE emp_recherché.idEmploye = id_employe
    group by emp_recherché.IDEMPLOYE ,emp_recherché.NOMEMPLOYE;
    RETURN data_emp;
END;    
/
```